# Full-Text Search against serial numbers?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, microsoft-dynamics

Using Dynamics 365 with MSSQL. There is an option to enable Full Text Search, however once it is enabled we cannot search by partial serial numbers.

For instance, KN567228 shows in the full text catalog but trying to search for 7228 will return no results. The Stoplist is empty, so that isn't the cause. This is a unique situation for Full-Text Search because there really isn't a thesaurus or wordbreaker that could break down serial numbers in a meaningful way. But I thought the search would work for partial text (like searching for 7228 in KN567228).

**Should I just not be using Full-Text Search in this scenario?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full-Text Search would be able to efficiently [Search for a word with a prefix (Prefix Term)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15#Prefix_Term) or [Search for a specific word or phrase (Simple Term)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15#Simple_Term), but not a suffix as you described. You can achieve what you need using [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

As you can see in Eugene Elutin's answer for a [Using Full-Text Search](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/using-full-text-search) thread:

> partial and suffix match in T-SQL can be only done using LIKE, which
>   will do full table scan to find relevant rows.

Here's [one way of doing the search you described](https://answers.sqlperformance.com/questions/1889/how-to-do-suffix-search-on-full-text-indexed-table.html)

> Full-text search only supports prefix search. In some circumstances,
>   reversing the string, indexing that, and then searching for the
>   reverse of the suffix can be made to work reasonably well.
>   Fundamentally, though, FTS is not designed for the purpose you
>   require.

But that approach would fail to find this other serial KN56**7228**1 when trying to search for 7228.